# Exporting pdf to excel

Tags: excel, vba, adobe

In Adobe DC Pro, you have the option to export your pdf to excel 2003 spreadsheet by first going to "Export PDF", next by choosing "XML Spreadsheet 2003" and last by choosing the setting "Create Worksheet for each page."

I can't find any code that does this in excel vba.

My question is, how do I make excel complete this option through VBA? Just saving it as SaveAS FileFormat:=XlFileFormat.xlXMLSpreadsheet only makes it a xml spreadsheet, not "creating the worksheet for each page" that Adobe Pro makes.

Thanks

Comment: "Just saving it as SaveAS " - what is the "it" in this sentence?  Are you working with a PDF, or an Excel worksheet/workbook ?

Comment: I'm working with both. I want excel to export a pdf to an xmlspreadsheet with worksheet for each page as you would  if you wanted to do that through just Adobe. I can do this just through Adobe Pro, I want to be able to have a excel macro complete this.

Comment: What's the source of the PDF?

Comment: It's Adobe Pro is the source. So there any coding I can use in excel that can mimick Adobe Pro? For example in Adobe Pro, I can export an PDF as an xml spreadsheet 2003 and create worksheet for each page, can excel do that as a macro?

Comment: I'd guess that's something specific to Acrobat.  As far as I know Excel doesn't have PDF conversion capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the **Adobe Acrobat 10.0 Type Library** reference, that comes with Adobe Acrobat Pro.

**Here is an example:**

This code will open a PDF file and assign each PDF page to individual worksheets.

```
Option Explicit
Sub PDF_To_Excel()

Dim PDF_ As Acrobat.AcroPDDoc
Dim Hilight_Text As Acrobat.AcroHiliteList
Dim PDF_Page As Acrobat.AcroPDPage
Dim Page_Text As Acrobat.AcroPDTextSelect
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Count_Page As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
Dim PDF_Text_Str As String
Dim Hold_Txt As Variant

Set PDF_ = New Acrobat.AcroPDDoc
Set Hilight_Text = New Acrobat.AcroHiliteList

Hilight_Text.Add 0, 32767

With PDF_

.Open "C:\ED5049PX2.pdf"
Count_Page = .GetNumPages

For i = 1 To Count_Page

PDF_Text_Str = ""

Set PDF_Page = .AcquirePage(i - 1)
Set Page_Text = PDF_Page.CreateWordHilite(Hilight_Text)

If Not Page_Text Is Nothing Then

With Page_Text

For j = 0 To .GetNumText - 1
PDF_Text_Str = PDF_Text_Str & .GetText(j)
Next j

End With

End If

Set ws = Worksheets.Add(, Worksheets(Sheets.Count))

With ws
.Name = "Page-" & i

If PDF_Text_Str <> "" Then

Hold_Txt = Split(PDF_Text_Str, vbCrLf)

For k = 0 To UBound(Hold_Txt)

PDF_Text_Str = CStr(Hold_Txt(k))
If Left(PDF_Text_Str, 1) = "=" Then PDF_Text_Str = "'" & PDF_Text_Str
.Cells(k + 1, 1).Value = PDF_Text_Str

Next k

Else
.Cells(1, 1).Value = "No text found in page " & i
End If

.Cells.Select
.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

End With

Next

.Close

End With

MsgBox ("Done")

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still have a problem with Page_Text is Nothing. Even though I have a pdf open, it seems like it doesn't read the Page_Text. Here is the code:

```
.Open "C:\User\test.pdf"
Count_Page=.GetNumPages

For I=1 to Count_Page
PDF_Text_Str=""
Set PDF_Page=.AcquirePage(i-1)
Set Page_Text=PDF_Page.CreateWordHilite(Hilight_Text)
If Not Page_Text is Nothing then
With Page_Text
For j=0 to .GetNumText  -1
PDF_Text_Str=PDF_Text_Str & .GetText(j)
Next j
End With
End if
```

Thanks